# Adding an overlay using jquery-ui-map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui-map

I am using

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_tutorial

The documentation is pretty poor when it comes to overlays.

What is the recommended way adding an google maps overlay using jquery-ui-map?

My use case is having an search as overlay...the overlay will call a view
returning the search results as markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no method for adding custom overlays, You'll need to create it by using the methods of google's API.

But in that special case it may be sufficient to add a custom control to the map by using **addControl** .

You find a demo in the ZIP-package, **jquery-google-maps-filtering.html** . It adds an select-list to the map for filtering, should be easy to adapt it to your needs.